# View is not updating in Ajax request in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

I am getting data from the json file, for the first time data is getting retrieved from the json file but after that if json file is updated, the values does not get updated in the view.  In other words, json file is not in sync with the view.

I am new to Angular and I am not able to understand, why is this happening and how to resolve this issue.
Script that I am using.

```
var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);
var model = {
    user: "Adam"
};
todoApp.run(function($http) {
    $http.get("todo.json").then(function(response) {
        model.items = response.data;

    });
});
todoApp.filter("checkedItems", function(){
  return function(items, showComplete){
    var resultArr = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item){
      if(item.done==false || showComplete==true){
        resultArr.push(item);
      }
    });
    return resultArr;
   }
});
todoApp.controller("Todoctrl", function($scope){
   $scope.todo = model;

   $scope.incompleteCount = function(){
     var count=0;
     angular.forEach($scope.todo.items, function(item){
       if(!item.done) {count++}
     });
     return count;
   }

   $scope.warningClass = function(){
     return ($scope.incompleteCount()<3 ? "label-success" : "label-warning");
   }

  $scope.newTodo = function(actionText){
    $scope.todo.items.push({action:actionText, done:false });
  }
});
```

todo.json file

```
[
    { "action": "Buy Flowers", "done": false },
    { "action": "Get Shoes", "done": false },
    { "action": "Collect Tickets", "done": true },
    { "action": "Study Geology", "done": false }
]
```

html code

```
<body ng-controller="Todoctrl">
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>{{ todo.user }}'s To Do List
    <span class="label label-default" ng-class="warningClass()"
      ng-hide="incompleteCount() == 0">
      {{incompleteCount()}}
    </span>
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="actionText">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="newTodo(actionText)">Add</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Done</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in todo.items | checkedItems:showComplete | orderBy: 'action'">
        <td>{{item.action}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="showComplete"> Show Complete</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use $scope which works for two way data binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong.

**First**: Use a service for your `$http` call.

```
angular.module('todoApp')
.service('JSONService', function($http){

    this.getItems = function(){
        $http.get("todo.json")
        .then(function(response) {
             return response.data;
        });

    }
});
```

This way, all you have to do is call `getItems()` again when JSON is updated.

**Secondly**: I see you're using `run` to set the `model` object, and then getting it through the controller. Don't do that.
Instead use a service for that too, which will get initialized in the start of your application, and be active throughout. Plus, it won't pollute the global namespace or `$rootScope`.

```
angular.module('todoApp')
.service('ModelService', function(JSONService){
    this.model = {
        user: "Adam",
        items: []
    };

    // code to fetch items; could put in a function as well
    JSONService.getItems()
    .then(function(items){
        this.model.items = items;
    }) 
});
```

**Thirdly**: Use your service created in the first point in your controller to populate the `todo` object. Whenever your JSON updates, send an event to update your service and controller.

```
// in your controller
$scope.todo = ModelService.model;
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope you can 't use inside **.run()**.

```
var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);
var model = {
    user: "Adam"
};
todoApp.run(function ($http, $rootScope) {
    $http.get("todo.json").then(function (response) {
        model.items = response.data;
        $rootScope.model = model; // Use model in html page
    });
});

todoApp.controller("Todoctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.todo = {};
    $scope.$watch('model', function () {
        $scope.todo = $rootScope.model;
    });

    $scope.incompleteCount = function () {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todo.items, function (item) {
            if (!item.done) {
                count++
            }
        });
        return count;
    }

    $scope.warningClass = function () {
        return ($scope.incompleteCount() < 3 ? "label-success" : "label-warning");
    }

    $scope.newTodo = function (actionText) {
        $scope.todo.items.push({
            action: actionText,
            done: false
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: After using $rootScope as well, its not syncing with the json file.

Comment: sorry,
You need to modify in HTML from todo.user to model.user

Comment: That is not the problem, it is not coming from json file.  Problem is in the data, that is coming from the json file.

Comment: reading file is async operation but your controller load before that so whenever data comes you have to update the controller. I have modified answer It might help.

Answer (score 0):

in angular we use *$scope* variable to bind view elements to the values in the controller. But this $scope variable is not available in *run*. So instead we use *$rootScope*

*$rootScope* is the scope created on the HTML element that contains the *ng-app* directive.

The *rootScope* is available in the entire application.

```
var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);
todoApp.run(function($http, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.model = {
        user: "Adam",
        items: []
    };
    $http.get("todo.json").then(function(response) {
        $rootScopr.model.items = response.data;

    });
});
```

Comment: why $rootscope?

Comment: @brk, because `$scope` not happens in the `run`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think your Http.get function should be in your run but rather in your Todoctrl controller.Then you can use $rootScope to distribute the data elsewhere because at the moment you don't know if it works.

Secondly, if the get works and does not update try use this :
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Thirdly use chrome developer tools to debug line by line